# JavaScript NaN with BibInt return strange types

Tags: javascript, nan, primitive-types, bigint

I can understand why NaN is a 'number' but can someone explain to me why

```js
console.log(typeof 1n+NaN);
console.log(typeof NaN+1n);
```

There is no such types in documentation.

Comment: The first is doing `(typeof 1n)+NaN`, and the second is doing `(typeof NaN)+1n`. The results you see are due to string concatenation. It's not doing `typeof (...)`. See [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because return type of `typeof` is `string` and you don't use brackets.

It equals to:

```
typeof(Nan); //'number'
'number' + 1n; //'number1'
```